# GCMIntentService Slow down Internet on My Android Phone

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Hi guys i am facing a strange problem, when i implement GCMintentService in My Application, My Application Calling Time to Webservice gets Out, i am getting Timedout response from webservice with `GCMintentService` Permission.

When i disabled those permission my App is communicating with web server fine, I am not understanding how to resolve the issue.

Any Clue or suggestion much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Manifest File here

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CLEAR_APP_CACHE" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <application
        android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.app.ApplicationController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:allowClearUserData="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.ForgotPasswordActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_forgot_password"
            android:parentActivityName="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.HomeActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustNothing" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.OwnAlertDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.AlertDetailsActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.UsersFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.GroupFragment"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|stateHidden" >
        </activity>


        <receiver
            android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.app.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.app.GcmIntentService" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Android Class Code**

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Application;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Build;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyLog;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class ApplicationController extends Application {
    /**
     * Log or request TAG
     */
    static Context context;


public static final String TAG = "VolleyPatterns";
    /**
     * Global request queue for Volley
     */
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

//  public static String APID;

    String SENDER_ID = "643413423722";

//  public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
//  public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";

private static final String PREFS_NAME = "Preference";
public static SharedPreferences settings;

GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
SharedPreferences prefs;

public static String regid;

/**
 * A singleton instance of the application class for easy access in other
 * places
 */
private static ApplicationController sInstance;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    // initialize the singleton
    sInstance = this;
    context = this;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyLifecycleHandler());
    }

    settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
    if (servicesOK()) {
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        regid = getRegistrationId(sInstance);

        if (regid.isEmpty()) {
            registerInBackground();
        }
    }

    // AirshipConfigOptions options = AirshipConfigOptions
    // .loadDefaultOptions(getBaseContext());
    // options.developmentAppKey = "Ex4yMwmKRde-kbuxeR2PkA";
    // options.developmentAppSecret = "Iy5B_q4_QsWJO-ax0aivgw";
    //
    // options.gcmSender = "643413423722";
    // options.transport = "gcm";
    //
    // options.inProduction = false; // determines which app key to use
    //
    // // Take off initializes the services
    // UAirship.takeOff(this, options);
    // PushManager.enablePush();
    // PushManager.shared().setIntentReceiver(IntentReceiver.class);
    //
    // CustomPushNotificationBuilder nb = new
    // CustomPushNotificationBuilder();
    //
    // nb.layout = R.layout.notificationlayout;
    //
    // nb.layoutIconDrawableId = R.drawable.icon;
    //
    // nb.layoutIconId = R.id.icon;
    // nb.layoutSubjectId = R.id.subject;
    // nb.layoutMessageId = R.id.message;
    //
    // nb.constantNotificationId = 100;
    //
    // PushPreferences prefs = PushManager.shared().getPreferences();
    // prefs.setSoundEnabled(true);
    // prefs.setVibrateEnabled(true);
    // //
    // APID = settings.getString("token", null);
    //
    // if (APID == null) {
    //
    // String apid = PushManager.shared().getAPID();
    //
    // if (apid == null) {
    // new Thread() {
    // @Override
    // public void run() {
    // while (ApplicationController.APID == null) {
    // ApplicationController.APID = PushManager.shared()
    // .getAPID();
    // try {
    // Thread.sleep(100);
    // } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    // e.printStackTrace();
    // }
    // }
    // }
    // }.start();
    // } else {
    // APID = apid;
    // }
    // //
    // SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    // editor.putString("token", APID);
    // editor.commit();
    // }
}

private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
    // String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
    String registrationId = settings.getString("token", "");
    if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
        return "";
    }
    // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
    // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
    // app version.
    int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION,
            Integer.MIN_VALUE);
    int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
    if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
        Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
        return "";
    }
    return registrationId;
}

private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    // This sample app persists the registration ID in shared preferences,
    // but
    // how you store the regID in your app is up to you.
    return getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}

private class GetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String msg = "";
        try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            }
            regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);

            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
            // If there is an error, don't just keep trying to register.
            // Require the user to click a button again, or perform
            // exponential back-off.
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString("token", regid);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }

}

private void registerInBackground() {
    new GetTask().execute(null, null, null);
}

public boolean servicesOK() {
    int isAvailable = GooglePlayServicesUtil
            .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (isAvailable == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        return true;
    } else if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(isAvailable)) {
        // Dialog dialog =
        // GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(isAvailable,
        // this, 9001);
        // dialog.show();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Can't connect to Google Play Services",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    return false;
}

public static Context getContext() {
    return context;
}

/**
 * @return ApplicationController singleton instance
 */
public static synchronized ApplicationController getInstance() {
    return sInstance;
}

/**
 * @return The Volley Request queue, the queue will be created if it is null
 */
public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
    // lazy initialize the request queue, the queue instance will be
    // created when it is accessed for the first time
    if (mRequestQueue == null) {
        mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
    }

    return mRequestQueue;
}

/**
 * Adds the specified request to the global queue, if tag is specified then
 * it is used else Default TAG is used.
 * 
 * @param req
 * @param tag
 */
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);

    VolleyLog.d("Adding request to queue: %s", req.getUrl());

    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

/**
 * Adds the specified request to the global queue using the Default TAG.
 * 
 * @param req
 * @param tag
 */
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
    // set the default tag if tag is empty
    req.setTag(TAG);

    getRequestQueue().add(req);
}

/**
 * Cancels all pending requests by the specified TAG, it is important to
 * specify a TAG so that the pending/ongoing requests can be cancelled.
 * 
 * @param tag
 */
public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
    if (mRequestQueue != null) {
        mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
    }
}
}
```

**GCMIntentService**

```
package com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.app;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.HomeActivity;
import com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.R;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;

public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    boolean foreground = false;
    Context context;

public GcmIntentService() {
    super("Some Value here");
    context = this;
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
        foreground = MyLifecycleHandler.isApplicationInForeground();
    } else {
        foreground = ForegroundCheckTask.isAppOnForeground(context);
    }
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
    // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
    // in your BroadcastReceiver.
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

    if (!extras.isEmpty()) { // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
        /*
         * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that
         * GCM will be extended in the future with new message types, just
         * ignore any message types you're not interested in, or that you
         * don't recognize.
         */
        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                    + extras.toString());
            // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE
                .equals(messageType)) {
            sendNotification(extras.getString("payload"));
        }
    }
    // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

// Put the message into a notification and post it.
// This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
// a GCM message.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    SQLiteDatabase db;
    String userid = null;
    db = openOrCreateDatabase("PeacekeeperDB.db", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users(user_id VARCHAR, email VARCHAR, name VARCHAR, password VARCHAR, phone VARCHAR, profilepicture VARCHAR, latitude VARCHAR, longitude VARCHAR, location VARCHAR, groupid VARCHAR, groupname VARCHAR, creatorid VARCHAR, alertid VARCHAR, message VARCHAR, alert_time VARCHAR, type VARCHAR, alertcreator_id VARCHAR, status VARCHAR, joingroup VARCHAR, neighbour_id VARCHAR, alert_image VARCHAR);");
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Users", null);
    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
        c.moveToFirst();
        userid = c.getString(0);
        c.close();
    }

    db.close();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);

    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.putExtra("message", msg);

    if (foreground) {
        if (userid != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("PeaceKeeper")
                .setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);

        // mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    } else {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
                this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                .setContentTitle("PeaceKeeper")
                .setStyle(
                        new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
                .setContentText(msg);
        mBuilder.setSound(Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI);
        if (userid != null) {
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
                    0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

}

**BroadCastReciever**

```
package com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

boolean foreground = false;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

}

Comment: Please post your Logcat, manifest and relevant code.

Comment: post your code or logcat

Comment: I have Posted my Code there.

Comment: Please include the code of your GCMBroadcastReceiver and GCMIntentService.

Comment: i Have put those classes here @Eran

Answer (score 2):

You can add GcmIntentService under your application package name because this service call [application package name].GcmIntentService via Broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question what's the exact problem you are experiencing, but I see some problems in your manifest and code :

I the broadcast receiver declaration you should specify your package name in the category :

Change this :

```
<category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
```

to this :

```
<category android:name="com.citrusbits.peacekeeper" />
```

Your broadcast receiver has this code :

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
        GcmIntentService.class.getName());
```

`context.getPackageName()` returns `com.citrusbits.peacekeeper`, but your intent service is in `com.citrusbits.peacekeeper.app`.

You should change it to :

```
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(GcmIntentService.class.getPackage().getName(),
        GcmIntentService.class.getName());
```

Comment: My Question is with Push Permission enabled other call to web services are failing it seems it takes all the bandwidth for that application.